# Endpoint target type 'DomainName' is not allowed for this profile

Tags: azure-traffic-manager

I am trying to create a new traffic manager profile of either Performance or Weight configuration but I keep getting stuck when trying to add an Azure Endpoint.

I have a two public IP inside of Azure, one with an optional DNS name, one with out.

When I try to add either of these as an endpoint, I get the following error message:

The one with a dns name on it:

Failed to save configuration changes to Traffic Manager profile 'profilename'. Error: Endpoint target type, 'DomainName', is not allowed for this profile. Valid values are: IPv4Address.

The one without a dns name:

No DNS name is configured.

If i choose External Endpoint and add the IPv4 directly it will work.

I tried with several different Traffice Manager profiles.. Is there a secret that I am missing out on? I am stuck..

Answer (score 0):

Usually, There are [three types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-endpoint-types) of endpoint supported by Traffic Manager:

> - **Azure endpoints** are used for services hosted in Azure.
> - **External endpoints** are used for IPv4/IPv6 addresses, FQDNs, or for services hosted outside Azure that can either be on-premises or
>   with a different hosting provider.
> - **Nested endpoints** are used to combine Traffic Manager profiles to create more flexible traffic-routing schemes to support the needs
>   of larger, more complex deployments.
>
> ...
>
> Azure endpoints are used for Azure-based services in Traffic Manager.
> The following Azure resource types are supported:
>
> PaaS cloud services. Web Apps Web App Slots PublicIPAddress resources
> (which can be connected to VMs either directly or via an Azure Load
> Balancer). **The publicIpAddress must have a DNS name assigned to be
> used in a Traffic Manager profile**.

In this case, when you add a public IP address **in the same subscription** as an Azure endpoint, it will grey out if no DNS name configured in the Azure portal. You could add it when the public IP address configured with Azure provided DNS name like `somedns.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com`, this works on my side.

For example, there is a public IP address with the DNS name used for an Azure load balancer frontend.
[image]